# Cannot connect to my remote server via ssh

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys

I'm trying to connect to a remote AWS (Ubuntu) server using SSH and keep getting this error msg:

```
Load key "/home/potatouser/.ssh/dashboard.pub": invalid format
Permission denied (publickey).
```

On my local machine, under `~/.ssh/config` I have this set:

```
Host someserver
    User potatouser
    HostName serverone.mysite.com
    Port 22

Host dashboard
    User potatouser
    HostName ec2-66-66-66-666.compute666.amazonaws.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/dashboard.pub
    Port 22
```

Running in the terminal: `ssh someserver` works fine, asks for a password, and connects me.

Trying to connect to the second server with a public-key / private key (`IdentityFile ~/.ssh/dashboard`, i tried both) - results the same error.

> -rwx------  1 potatouser potatouser  955 Feb 13 16:49 dashboard
>
> -rwx------  1 potatouser potatouser  398 Feb 13 17:13 dashboard.pub

On my AWS server, under my user, `~/.ssh/` there is a file named: `authorized_keys` which has something that looks like a public key inside of it, looks something like this:

```
ssh-rsa asdasfagdsasfafsafadsfafs..... 
....
...
```

Answer (score 3):

> Load key "/home/potatouser/.ssh/dashboard **.pub**": invalid format
>   Permission denied (**publickey**).

You need to authenticate to a remote system with your **private** key, not your public key.

Try

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/dashboard
```

if that is the private key associated with the   `~/.ssh/dashboard.pub` public key file.

Comment: I tried both (as mentioned in my main post).

Comment: When you open  ~/.ssh/dashboard in a text editor, does it look like a private key?

Comment: Yes, it seems like i had the worng key. I changed my keys, now I get `Permission denied (publickey).` :(